# Edit button with comments using MooTools/AJAX

Tags: ajax, mootools

So I'm using a PHP API to interact with, to build a forum using MooTools. I can get comments from my database and add comments, but I want to inject an edit button to coincide with each comment.

I inject the comments using:

```
function domReady() {
    $('newComment').addEvent('submit', addComment);
}

function addComment(e){
e.stop();
var req = new Request({
    url:'control.php?action=insertPost',
    onSuccess:addajaxSuccess
}).post(this);
}


function addajaxSuccess(idNo) {
new Element('span',{
    'text':'Post successful.'
}).inject($(newComment));
$('commentList').empty();
domReady();
}
```

I want to attach an edit button to each comment injected, and add an event listener on the button to change the comment into a textarea for editting, with an update button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your example, it looks like after the successful Request, you just add a success message to the 'newComment' element.  Does the 'newComment' element already include the comment text, and is that where you want to add the button and textarea?  It looks like you already know how to add event listeners, create elements, and inject them into others - so it's tough to tell what you need help with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind a global events to a dynamic content you have better look into [Element Delegation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation) In mootools.

Basically it's give you the ability to bind event to some container and "listen" to events  of that children container base on selectors. I made you a little example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xwpmv/

```
mainContainer.addEvents({
    'click:relay(.mt-btn)': function (event, target) {
        var btn = target;
        if(btn.get('value') == 'Edit'){
            btn.set('value','Done Editing');
            var content = btn.getPrevious();
            content.setStyle('display','none');

            var textarea = new Element('textarea').set('text',content.get('text'));
            textarea.inject(btn,'before');

        }
        else{
             btn.set('value','Edit');    
             var textarea = btn.getPrevious();
            var new_value = textarea.get('value');
            textarea.destroy();
            var content = btn.getPrevious();
            content.set('text',new_value);
            content.setStyle('display','block');
        }
    }
});
```

Here you can see the mainContainer listen to the click event of every element who has `mt-btn` class (the buttons)

- You have several errors in your code but maybe it is just an example so I didn't relate to it.

Comment: No errors, I just used unobtrusive JavaScript, the example really helped, just adapted it to work with event listeners. Thank you.